# Hash Map Usage and Idea

Tags: java, hashmap

I have been working in Java for the last 6 months and have been using Hash Maps

What is the basic idea of a Hash Map ? I am using it as it easy for me to store so much data with direct key references rather than having to iterate through an arraylist ?

Where is the power of Hash Map seen ?  What is the scientific idea behind this data structure ?

Comment: Isn't it all written in HashMap javadoc ? The use of hash code to store keys, and the way these keys will be browsed ? And the subtle, yet totally lethal, influence incompatible equals and hashCode have on such maps ?

Answer (score 1):

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) on Hash Tables should be able to help you.  In particular check out the [Uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Uses) section.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap works on Key/Value based architecture. Duplicate keys are not allowed. Hashmap uses hashcode to store/retrieve values from the bucket. The purpose of ArrayList is different. It is just a list of items/objects. You have to use index (int) to retrieve an item from ArrayList. Hashmaps are even more powerful. It allows any Object to be used as a key.

This link should help you to understand things better:
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html